# avoid multiple union all in cte

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause, common-table-expression, union-all

Hi I have a CTE with 5 inner joins and a where clause which is reducing by one.
the sample code looks like below. but the actual code has more complex logic

```
;With CTE_EG AS
(
 select *,
-1 as offset from a 
 inner join a1 on a1.id=a.id
 inner join a2 on a1.id=a2.id
 inner join a3 on a1.id=a3.id
where a1.offset = a2.quarter-1
union all
 select *,
-2 as offset from a 
 inner join a1 on a1.id=a.id
 inner join a2 on a1.id=a2.id
 inner join a3 on a1.id=a3.id
where a1.offset = a2.quarter-2
union all
   ...
    )
```

this repeats till offset -4 and a1.offset = a2.quarter-4.
How can I avoid the same code to be repeated for so many times for only one where clause value. the actualy query has 5 inner joins and total 5 union all.
I can not remove the union all because that will generate in some calculation discrepancy.
I want something like when we pass an integer value n , the selects in between  union all should repeat with the changing where clause like a1.offset = a2.quarter-2 to a1.offset = a2.quarter-n
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

This should just be:

```
;With Numbers(n) as (
  select 1 union all select 2 union all
  select 3 union all select 4
), CTE_EG AS
(
 select *,
-n as offset from a 
 inner join a1 on a1.id=a.id
 inner join a2 on a1.id=a2.id
 inner join a3 on a1.id=a3.id
 inner join numbers n on a1.offset = a2.quarter-n
 )
```

I don't understand your point about not being able to remove the `UNION ALL`.